# Авторизация на Yobit.io по API

Tags: python-3.x, sha

Решено. Я шифровал ключ сообщением.

Доброго. 
Есть такой код.

```
import requests
import hmac, hashlib

request_url = "https://yobit.io/tapi"
request_body = bytes('method=getInfo&nonce=1'.encode('utf-8'))
apikey = 'F01C58D09F417509BB427FD2A3EA57DC'
apisecret = bytes('96e36a62ec51ff3be9c4ba0c510cd618'.encode('utf-8'))
signature = hmac.new(request_body, apisecret, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
http_headers = {
    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Key":apikey,
    "Sign":signature
}

req = requests.post(request_url,data='method=getInfo&nonce=1',headers=http_headers)
print(signature)
print(req.text)
```

Собственно он должен авторизоваться на бирже, но биржа отвечает что подпись моя не верна. Как верно подписать мои данные секретным ключем?

PS Ключ авторизован только на info

Описание api https://yobit.io/ru/api/

Comment: Я не верно подписываю данные. Если посчитать sha512 на каком либо сайте, то все авторизуется верно.

Comment: А пробовали просто через hashlib.sha512 считать, а не через hmac?